# Does UIApplication.shared.open(url) count as encryption?

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I’m having trouble understanding the Export Compliance Information on App Store Connect
In my app I use a simple piece of code to just open a webpage

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://test.com") {
     UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Do I need to mark that I use encryption because of this? If so do I qualify for exemptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** you don't need to mark that you uses encryption.